# Query working fine on PGAdmin but not on Terminal

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, psql

I am planning to create a cronjob that will change the password of my site every 15th day of the month. This is my .sh file

```
psql -U postgres -h (sample-host) (sample-db) -p (sample-port) -c "UPDATE web_user SET password_hash = '$2a$12$ohJ0j2Y9lRkO6Ld9MaiLuu7Q4hzYSr1IsM5SfY1SxAGk6fgn20aj2' WHERE email = 'email@email.com'"
```

When i run the query `UPDATE web_user SET password_hash ='$2a$12$ohJ0j2Y9lRkO6Ld9MaiLuu7Q4hzYSr1IsM5SfY1SxAGk6fgn20aj2' WHERE email = 'email@email.com';`  on pgadmin, everything is fine. The update is fine and the password is right. But when I run my .sh file on my machine(ubuntu 18.04), and even manually running it on the terminal, the result will be just `a`.

There are no errors messages or anything like that. Is there something that I missed? BTW the version of is postgresql 13.4.

Update: I just found out that special characters are causing the problem. it seems that the psql command does not allow special characters. The problem is I can't find any resources about these things.

Comment: You missed single quote `'` in email then how the query worked in pgadmin? Or you miss spell it here

Comment: sorry just misspelled it here. will edit. thanks!

Comment: `psql -U postgres -h (sample-host) (sample-db) -p (sample-port) -c "UPDATE web_user SET password_hash = '$(echo '$2a$12$ohJ0j2Y9lRkO6Ld9MaiLuu7Q4hzYSr1IsM5SfY1SxAGk6fgn20aj2')' WHERE email = 'email@email.com'"`

Comment: It is a shell issue, not directly a psql issue.  It is the shell which interprets the $2 and the others as being shell variable interpolations.

Comment: I will look more into that. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the special characters you need to a workaround
I tried in powershell, may be work in linux terminal

before:

```
postgres=# select * from web_user;
 pass | email
------+-------
(0 rows)
```

used echo to output the password_hash as it contains special characters.

`psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres -p 5432 -c "UPDATE web_user SET pass = '$(echo '$2a$12$ohJ0j2Y9lRkO6Ld9MaiLuu7Q4hzYSr1IsM5SfY1SxAGk6fgn20aj2')' WHERE email = 'email@email.com'"`

output:

```
postgres=# select * from web_user;
                             pass                             |      email
--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------
 $2a$12$ohJ0j2Y9lRkO6Ld9MaiLuu7Q4hzYSr1IsM5SfY1SxAGk6fgn20aj2 | email@email.com
(1 row)
```